# Vue.js Router Link Not Updating

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am encountering an issue that I have reproduced with the following simplified code:

App.vue

```
      <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
      <router-link :to="{name: 'View1', params: {myprop: 'hello 1'}}"> |
         View 1 - Param 1
      </router-link>
      <router-link :to="{name: 'View1', params: {myprop: 'hello 2'}}"> |
         View 1 - Param 2
      </router-link>
      <router-view :key='$route.path' />
```

View1.vue

```
    <template>
      <div>
        My prop = {{myprop}}
      </div>
    </template>
```

If I start on the Home link and click “View 1 - Param 1”, I am taken to View1 and see “My prop = hello 1”. This is as expected.

If I then go back to the home page and click “View 1 - Param 2”, I am taken to View1 and see “My prop = hello 2”. This is also as expected.

Here’s where the trouble starts. If I click “View 1 - Param 1” while I am already on “View 1 - Param 2”, then I am taken to View1, but the message does not update. So, I see “My prop = hello 2” again instead of seeing “My prop = hello 1”.

My understanding is that Vue is not rerendering View1 as an optimization since the “from” view and “to” view are the same, but clearly that is not the behavior I would like.

I did some research on this and came across a video that suggested using “key=’$route.path’” in the view tag would address this. However, this is not solving the issue for me.

What is the correct way to address this issue, please?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-thunder-v7fch. Correct me if my example wrong.

Comment: Brilliant, you solved the problem for me.  I was not including the prop in the router path.  Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. By the way the answer from @s4k1b is also right for the point that why your key is not working.

Answer (score 5):

Your solution won't work because the `$route.path` string does not contain the query parameters. So, when you change go from "View 1 - Param 2" to "View 1 - Param 1", the `$route.path` remains same, and does not update the view.

Use `$route.fullPath` this will update the view as it contains the The full resolved URL including query and hash.

```html
<router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
<router-link :to="{name: 'View1', params: {myprop: 'hello 1'}}"> |
   View 1 - Param 1
</router-link>
<router-link :to="{name: 'View1', params: {myprop: 'hello 2'}}"> |
   View 1 - Param 2
</router-link>
<router-view :key='$route.fullPath' />
```

Alternatively, you can add a watcher to the route query parameter inside your "View1.vue". This way you wont have to add `key` to your `router-view`

View1.vue

```html
<template>
  <div>
     My prop = {{pageProp}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      pageProp: ""
    }
  },
  watch: {
    "$route.query": {
      immediate: true,
      handler(n) {
        this.pageProp = n.myProp
      }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this information.  It turns out that I was not including the prop in my router's path.  Once that was added, the code worked as is.  (BTW, when I tried the watch routine, I got a syntax error unless I removed the ":" from "handler(n):".

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```js
<router-view :key ='$route.params'/>
```

instead of using

```
<router-view :key ='$route.path'/>
```

In my case it worked.